# IntelliJ beginning of file keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-13

Is there a keyboard shortcut to move to the beginning of a file? I checked IntelliJ's [Keymap for Mac OS X](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/index.jsp) and it doesn't list anything for navigating to the start of a file.

Answer (score 429, accepted):

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Kirby, those of us on Mac laptops that lack the home/end keys thank you greatly.

Comment: Thanks. Another keytip: use fn+up or down arrow to move a page up or down.

Comment: To select a block quickly: SHIFT-FN-CMD + UP/DOWN ARROW KEYS .. this solution got me on the right path - thanks!

Comment: on windows, it is by default **Ctrl + Home** to go to the beginning of a file and **Ctrl+End** for the end. **vote this comment if you are on windows!**

Comment: That's weird, why can't Command+Up work, like in literally every other text editing application?

Comment: For those who want to replace this shortcut search for "Move Caret to Text Start" in keymap settings

Comment: I am using fn+cmd+left-arrow to go to the begining od file and fn+cmd+right-arrow to go to the end of the document. I'm working MacBook Pro.
Ref: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206735685/comments/206620769

Answer (score 115):

Edit the Intellij Preferences -> KeyMap -> Editor Actions entries for "Move Caret to Text Start" and "Move Caret to Text End".  If you set those to Command+UpArrow and Command+DownArrow, it'll work like a normal text editor.  I have no idea why that isn't the default in Intellij instead of the seemingly pointless "scroll one line" feature.

Comment: "seemingly" is a kind way to put it.

Comment: The default setting for Text Start is Command+Home which in macbook's keyboard should be Fn+Command+Left

Comment: Excellent. I was searching for a consistent behavior between my mac and my (regular/PC) external keyboard. On my mac there's no "Home" and "End" Buttons, and the external keyboard the "fn" is not located in the bottom left - so this is the solution I sought.

Comment: One gotcha point is that you'll probably want to do the same for "Move Caret to Text [Start/End] with Selection" as well, with the shift key included.

Answer (score 23):

On Mac, <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd> move to the top and bottom of the file.

On a Mac laptop, there are no home or end keys. Many key combinations with <kbd>option</kbd>/<kbd>function</kbd> keys produce missing keys and do other neat things. For instance, using <kbd>function</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>function</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> will provide windows-style <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd> behaviour while <kbd>function</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>function</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> will provide <kbd>page up</kbd> and <kbd>page down</kbd> behaviour. Superuser has [more information](https://superuser.com/questions/132719/how-do-i-type-home-end-pageup-pagedown-on-a-macbook-pro/132722#132722).

Also, if you open the `Keyboard` preferences pane and look at the `Input Sources` tab, you will find that the displayed keyboard changes as you press modifier keys such shift, option and function. Your keyboard probably does way more than you thought.

Comment: Valid, I assume, only for keyboards that have a home and end key

Comment: Have you owned a laptop in the past ten years?  If you haven't, I'd suggest getting one, it's easier than carrying the aluminum tower around.

Comment: The tone of this answer is pretty condescending. The laptop shortcuts could have been explained in a more neutral way.

Comment: @ryanbrainard That's mainly because I get annoyed with the low amount of research that people seem to put in. Even the [wikipedia article on the Home Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_key#Mac_OS_X) provides this info. Anyway, I reworded the section.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is not correct. To move to the beginning/end of a file, use ctrl+home/ctrl+end on Windows/Unix or command-home and command-end on the Mac, as @jackrabbit suggested.

ctrl+pageup (Move Caret to Page Top) moves the caret to the top of the viewable portion of the file (page, viewport). It also does not move the caret to the first column, it tries to stay in the same column that it was previously

Answer (score 5):

Just as an addition for clarity

For Windows,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> => Top

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> => Bottom

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> => Page Up

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> => Page Down

Answer (score 3):

Search the Keymap preference settings, and set your own key combination for "Move Caret to Text Start" and "Move Caret to Text End".  This has the behavior the OP intends, where the caret is moved to the very top of the text in file, and the very end.  :D

I am using IntelliJ 12, and LOVING IT!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
Page Up => fn + up

Page Down => fn + down
```